# Replacing certain values in data.frame in R

Tags: r, replace, match

I am trying to replace the NAs in "test" with the forecast values in "forecast".  I am trying to use match, but I can't figure it out. keep in mind the id and time create a two-part unique id.  Any suggestions?  ( keep in mind my data set is much larger than this example (rows=32000))

```
test = data.frame(id =c(1,1,1,2,2,2), time=c(89,99,109,89,99,109), data=c(3,4,NA,5,2,NA))
forecast = data.frame(id =c(1,2), time=c(109,109), data=c(5,1))
```

Desired output

```
out = data.frame(id =c(1,1,1,2,2,2), time=c(89,99,109,89,99,109), data=c(3,4,5,5,2,1))
```

Comment: Is every NA value being replaced with a forecast value, or will some remain NAs in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the `data.table` solution

```
test_dt <- data.table(test, key = c('id', 'time'))
forecast_dt <- data.table(test, key = c('id', 'time'))
forecast[test][,data := ifelse(is.na(data), data.1, data)]
```

EDIT. Benchmarking Tests: Data Table is ~ 3x faster even for a small dataset.

library(rbenchmark)

```
f_merge <- function(){
  out2 <- merge(test, forecast, by = c("id", "time"), all.x = TRUE)
  out2 <- transform(out2, 
   newdata = ifelse(is.na(data.x), data.y, data.x), data.x = NULL, data.y = NULL)
  return(out2)
}

f_dtable <- function(){
  test <- data.table(test, key = c('id', 'time'))
  forecast <- data.table(forecast, key = c('id', 'time'))
  test <- forecast[test][,data := ifelse(is.na(data), data.1, data)]
  test$data.1 <- NULL
  return(test)
}

benchmark(f_merge(), f_dtable(), order = 'relative', 
  columns = c('test', 'elapsed', 'relative'))

        test elapsed relative
2 f_dtable()    0.86     1.00
1  f_merge()    2.26     2.63
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `merge` to join the data together and then compute your new column in two steps:

```
out2 <- merge(test, forecast, by = c("id", "time"), all.x = TRUE)
> out2
  id time data.x data.y
1  1   89      3     NA
2  1   99      4     NA
3  1  109     NA      5
4  2   89      5     NA
5  2   99      2     NA
6  2  109     NA      1

#Compute new variable and clean up old ones:

out2 <- transform(out2, newdata = ifelse(is.na(data.x), data.y, data.x), data.x = NULL, data.y = NULL)
> out2
  id time newdata
1  1   89       3
2  1   99       4
3  1  109       5
4  2   89       5
5  2   99       2
6  2  109       1
```

Comment: The reason for my comment above was that I was going to suggest simply dropping the rows with `NA`s and then `rbind`ing the forecast values on, but that assumes every missing value is being forecast.

Comment: @Joran - that would be sneaky and fast. I like it. `merge` may get slow with lots of rows, so I was going to put together the equivalent `data.table()` answer too, but I bet your proposed solution would still be the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test$data[is.na(test$data)] <- forecast[((forecast$id %in% test$id) & (forecast$time %in% test$time)),]$data
```

Comment: Sorry this won't work.  I didn't specify initially that my data set is extremely large... so can't do anything manually.

Comment: My code will give you the same results as your desired output (out). I think you must edit your question to give some advice what is the problem you're trying to solve

Comment: It solves the *immediate* problem, but is not very scalable or flexible to other options. This is equivalent to `edit(test)` and changing things by hand...great for 6 lines of data, really bad for 6000.

Comment: Only if `test` and `forecast` are sorted by id and time first. You're also making assumptions about whether every missing value is being forecast, or only some.

Comment: I'm aswering the question with the data he provided. I cannot take care all the peculiarities there may be present in the data.

Comment: I wasn't criticizing, I was just answering your question.