# Replace value in Dataframe if flagged in another dataframe

Tags: r, loops, merge, replace

I have some values in a dataframe called 'values'

ie:

```
Sam Ned Ted Ann
500 430 57  212
410 265 69  341
189 554 153 457
236 311 590 271
50  568 234 442
```

And some quality control flags in a separate dataframe 'flags'

```
Sam$F   Ned$F   Ted$F   Ann$F
1   1   1   0 
0   0   1   0
0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0
```

I would like to replace the number in 'values' with NA if the equivalent entry in flags is a 1 i.e. resulting in the following

```
Sam Ned Ted Ann
NA  NA  NA  212
410 265 NA  341
189 554 NA  457
236 311 590 271
50  568 NA  442
```

This question is very similar to this one: [Replacing certain values in data.frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594747/replacing-certain-values-in-data-frame-in-r)

Which has been solved neatly with a 'merge tables' solution.

Except that I have a lot of data columns to perform this on, not just one. However I should be able to get the same 'merge tables' solution to work for me.

To merge the 2 tables (and replace 1s  with NA  I have used the following

```
F2 <-Flags
F2[F2 == "1"] <- "NA"
# Create identical column names for values and F2 for matching
samples <-colnames(Rvalues)
colnames(F2) <-samples
#Create an ID column for F2 and values
F2$ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
Rvalues$ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
out2 <- merge(Rvalues, F2, by = c("ID"), all.x = TRUE)
```

The resulting out2 dataframe is as follows:

```
ID  Sam.x   Ned.x   Ted.x   Ann.x   Sam.y   Ned.y   Ted.y   Ann.y 
1   1   500 430 57  212 NA  NA  NA  0
2   2   410 265 69  341 0   0   NA  0
3   3   189 554 153 457 0   0   NA  0
4   4   236 311 590 271 0   0   0   0
5   5   50  568 234 442 0   0   NA  0
```

So I would like to use the solution posted (by Chase) in the link above, within a loop to go through the columns for each sample.

I have tried the following:

```
for [i in samples]
{
out3 <- transform(out2, [i]$new = ifelse(is.na([i].x), [i].y, [i].x), [i].x = NULL, [i].y = NULL)}
```

It is not working (error message

```
"Error: unexpected '[' in:
"{
out3 <- transform(out2, newdata = ifelse(is.na(["")
```

So I have something wrong, without the [] brackets it also does not work.

Any fixes greatly appreciated, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 'values' and 'flags' data.frames have the same dimension and order of columns

```
values[flags == 1] <- NA
```

Comment: Wow that is so simple and so obvious, yes they are in the same dimension and order. Thank you. This makes the loop completely unnecessary. If for example the column orders were different, do you know if the loop was close?

Comment: If order of columns will be differrent in the data.frames then you can 1) sort columns to obtain identical order in both data.frames or 2) use some of `apply` family functions. For loops in R are usually quite slow and it's better to avoid their usage.